# How to convert a normal message into an embed message? discord.js

Tags: discord.js

so I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now. I couldn't find any solutions and I was wondering if you can actually do it.

I would like to have my discord bot to be able to delete the message that a user sent in the channel (suggestions) using `message.delete()` and then the bot sends an embed and the message that the user sent is the embed's description.

Sorry I don't have any code right now, however if you need the `index.js` or other files, I can send.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get message content

```js
let embedDescripton = message.content;
```

Create embed

```js
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(embedDescripton);
```

Send embed

```js
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Delete old message (bot needs permission to perform message deletion)

```js
message.delete();
```

I would recommend you to visit the official docs of [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) you can find everything you need there.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this as a command. I know the [command handling](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/) is everything but perfect. Nonetheless it shows how to [`fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch) the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) sent by the user, how to [`delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) it and how to send the new [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) with the content of the user message:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("!convert")) {
    const id = message.content.split(" ")[1];
    const userMessage = await message.channel.messages.fetch(id);

    await userMessage.delete();
    return message.channel.send(
      new Discord.MessageEmbed({ description: userMessage.content })
    );
  }
});

client.login("your-awesome-token");
```